# Declaring a variable as float I get  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Float field 

Tags: python, jython

I'm using jython for writing test cases and I need to declare a variable as float.
I am declaring this way:

```
width = float(10.0)
Height = float(40.0)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Float field com.ganz.tt.user.service.client.featurecodemanager.CreateVillagerSvc$Request.width to java.lang.Double
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to use [java double type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) instead of float. Python uses usually doubles to represent floats.

Comment: while declaring as double its not even going to next line......width = double(10.0f)  Height = double(40.0f)